# Using K means to map people to a group based on their score of a leader

Tags: javascript, data-science, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, k-means

I am attempting to create an algorithm to match people to a leader of a group. I've discovered K means clustering, and think this is the way to go. The project is in javascript so I've found [a package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/skmeans) on npm that implements K-means. Now I am confused as there aren't any examples I can find similar to this, but if I have 20 people who give scores to 4 people based on their ability to lead, how do I format my data to be used by the k-means to assign the 20 people to groups?

[A screenshot google sheets of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/175eF.png)

To be precise: based on that screenshot **I am trying to map the followers 2-20, to leaders L1-L4, based on their scores of the leaders** 0,0.5,1,1.5 with 1.5 being the highest score (shortest distance). Ideally having similar sized groups.

What I've tried:

```
var data = [[0.5,0.5,0,0],
            [1.5,0,0.5,0],
            [1.5,0,1.5,1],
            [1.5,0.5,0,0],
            [0.5,1.5,0,1],
            [0.5,1.5,0.5,1],
            [0.5,0.5,1,0],
            [1,0,1,1],
            [1.5,1.5,1,0.5],
            [0.5,1,0.5,1],
            [1,1,1,1],
            [1.5,1.5,0.5,1],
            [1,1.5,1,0.5],
            [0,1.5,0.5,1.5],
            [1.5,1,0.5,0],
            [0.5,0,0,1.5],
            [0.5,0,0,1.5],
            [1.5,0.5,1.5,1],
            [0.5,1.5,1,1]];

var res = skmeans(data,4);
```

But this just grouped the followers amongst themselves based on who scored the leaders similarly, instead of using the leaders as centroids. Open to other clustering formats, or if I'm completely off target info on better algorithms to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What K-means clustering does here is to get 4 arbitrary points and calculate shortest distance to each data point to create 4 clusters as you requested. Then it will get the MEAN value of each cluster formed after the first iteration to define centroids for the next iteration. Since the first iteration takes arbitrary points, the result you got is obvious.

Defining expected leaders as centroids instead of letting the algorithm to get arbitrary points as centroids might help.

```
skmeans(data,k,[centroids],[iterations])
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/skmeans#skmeansdatakcentroidsiterations

Comment: I tried `var center = [[1,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0], [0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,1]];
var res = skmeans(data,4,center);` and it didn't change the output at all, it ignored my centroids and used other ones. Also tried using 4 exact entries from the list `[0.5,0.5,0,0], [1.5,0,0.5,0],[1.5,0,1.5,1],[1.5,0.5,0,0],` and that also didn't work and it ignored them (the outputted centroids are completely different). Also tried just using [1,2,3,4] which is less dimensions but my intention, obviously didn't work.

Comment: How about adding `var center = [[1.5,0,0,0], [0,1.5,0,0], [0,0,1.5,0], [0,0,0,1.5]];`. It's the max value of each dimension. It will always end up with 4 centroids where the values are the mean value of the cluster. K-means is a classification algorithm and you can't get a leading data point from the algorithm. As a suggestion (This might not be ideal) what you can do is to check out newly created clusters separately and get the data point with max value for a dimension as a leader.

Comment: Yea I ended up realizing in the past hour or so that K-means works slightly differently than I thought. Thanks for the write up it helped me come to that conclusion. I did actually try 1.5 for the values shortly after using 1, forgot the values weren’t normalized. I think I might need to go back to the drawing board in terms of my algorithm.